# AppEngine:java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError in apphosting_java_openjre8

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am getting an error `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` in apphosting_java_openjre8,(/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/apphosting_java_openjre8/510ec52506d34156/lib/amd64/lib).
This happens when I try to generate my reports using jasper reports on AppEngine.

I appreciate your help on this.

Generating reports using jasper reports.

**error:** /base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/apphosting_java_openjre8/510ec52506d34156/lib/amd64/lib`

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, but using apache poi. It seems to be a problem loading system resurces as fonts.

Comment: This should be a comment